# Cómo cambiar funcionalidad de botón entre primer y segundo clic?

Tags: html5

Tengo un botón que de debe servir para dos funciones pero quiero que al 1er click salga la 1ra y al 2do la otra función, hice un ejemplo rapido

```
    <script>
        function AccionparacuandoelladigaqueSi (){
             document.getElementById("Titulo").innerHTML= "En serio?";
        }
        document.getElementById("button").onclick = function(){
            cambiar()
        }
    <script>
        function respuesta(){
            alert ('hola');
        }
    </script>
<input type="button" onclick="AccionparacuandoelladigaqueSi();respuesta()"; id="btnSi" value="Si"/>
```

*primero debería cambiar el cuerpo y luego salr la alerta pero trabajan al mismo timepo*

Comment: No se mucho de javascript pero puedes usar un **if**, en un elemento de tu html oculto podrías tener un valor que al dar clic al botón cambie, y cuando vuelvas a dar clic en el if lees el valor de ese elemento y si ha cambiado ejecutas la segunda función

Answer (score 0):

Si para ejecutar otra función después de la primera en un segundo clic puedes usar un if. El funcionamiento es sencillo creas un atributo donde almacenas un booleano. Al hacer click la función lee el booleano y así determina si es el primer click o segundo. Esto permite ejecutar dos diferentes funciones, en orden de click(Primero y segundo). Aquí el código de ejemplo.

```js
function Primero(){
  alert("primer click");
}

function Segundo(){
  alert("segundo click")
}

function clickenbtn(){
  let btn= document.getElementById("btn");
  btn.setAttribute("data-click",true);
  //
  btn.addEventListener("click",function(){
  if(eval( btn.getAttribute("data-click"))){
    Primero();
     btn.setAttribute("data-click",false);
  }else{
    Segundo();
  }
  
  })
 
}
clickenbtn();
```

```html
<button id="btn">Click</button>
```